# '&' or '=' in lambda capture expression?

Tags: c++11, lambda, stdthread

I'm trying to understand the implications of capturing variables by reference or by value in the following example use of a lambda expression.

```
/** Encapsulates the private implementation details of Thread. */
struct Thread::Impl
{
public:
    Impl() : m_queue(), m_thread()
    {
    }

private:
    Impl(const Impl&);
    const Impl& operator=(const Impl&);

    void run()
    {
        // do some work
    }

    std::unique_ptr<std::thread> m_thread;

    friend class Thread;
};

Thread::Thread() : m_impl(new Impl())
{
    // start the thread

    // ************************************
    // '=' or '&' in the the capture block?
    // ************************************
    m_impl->m_thread = std::unique_ptr<std::thread>(new std::thread( [&]{ m_impl->run(); } ));
}
```

Regardless of whether I use `&` or `=` in the capture block the above code works OK. So which should I use?

If I use `[&]`, `m_impl` is captured by reference, right?

If I use `[=]` `m_impl` is captured by value, right? But I don't understand why it compiles. What is it making a copy of? The copy ctor for Impl is disabled.

Comment: Why are you storing a `std::thread` in a `unique_ptr`? It's already movable, you can just use `std::thread` directly and avoid a heap allocation.

Comment: Because I saw this example from Herb Sutter and he knows better than me - http://www.drdobbs.com/article/print?articleId=225700095&siteSectionName=parallel

Comment: I don't know what Herb was thinking, but `thd = unique_ptr<thread>(
                  new thread( bind(&Active::Run, this) ) );` is utter nonsense. It should be simply `thd = std::thread(&Active::Run, this)`, without using `unique_ptr` or `bind`

Comment: Your code has a `Thread` class with a handle to an `Impl` class with a handle to a `std::thread` class which is a handle to a thread of execution. Too many handles!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I use `[&]`, `m_impl` is captured by reference, right? If I use `[=]` `m_impl` is captured by value, right?

Neither of those is true. `m_impl` isn't captured at all. In both cases, the `this` is captured. But since the `thread` is a member variable of the object whose `this` pointer your capturing, this (ha!) is safe.

Use whichever you prefer. Or `[this]`, if you want to be more explicit.

Comment: So `this` is either passed by value or by reference? i.e. the pointer or a copy of it?

Comment: @ksl Right. You either end up with a `Thread*` or a `Thread*&`.